# Bypass NoneType Exception while collecting data

Tags: xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am currently looping through an XML response and looking to match on a specific ID. I am then tracking back to the parent node to collect other data associated with it. During this process, if the ID is not matched I am unable to look at the parent node because of the value not existing and get a NoneType Exception Error. The goal is to capture the value that threw this error and bypass the Exception Error so I can keep moving through my list.

I've tried putting an if statement to change the value to string but the error is still thrown

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


url = "https://google.com/Clicks"

payload = {
            "start_date":"08/07/2019 21:42:00",
            "end_date":"08/07/2019 21:42:59",
            "offer_id":"284"
            }

r = requests.get(url, params=payload)

##print(r.text)
response = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

with open('TrackingIDs.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for data in csv_reader:
        trackingID = data['ID']



        matchedID = response.find(text=trackingID)
        parent = matchedID.parent.parent
        campaignID = parent.find('campaign_id').string
        affiliateID = parent.find('source_affiliate_id').string
        subID = parent.find('sub_id_1').string
        print(campaignID)
        print(affiliateID)
        print(subID)
```

The error is thrown after data my Tracking ID is imported from my CSV file and that ID is not found.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try and Expect blocks did the trick:

```
try:
            matchedID = response.find(text=trackingID)
            parent = matchedID.parent.parent
        except (AttributeError, NameError):
            print('ID not Found:', data['ID'])
        else:
            campaignID = parent.find('campaign_id').string
            affiliateID = parent.find('source_affiliate_id').string
            subID = parent.find('sub_id_1').string
            print('Tracking ID:', matchedID)
            print('Campaign ID:', campaignID)
            print('Affiliate ID:', affiliateID)
            print('Sub ID:', subID)
            c.writerow([matchedID, campaignID, affiliateID, subID])
```